# asp.net(VB)でボタンを押したら画面を閉じるようにしたい

Tags: asp.net

asp.net(VB)で作成した画面をiPhoneのsafariで開いているのですが、
"終了する"ボタンを押したらタブを消したいと考えています。
ボタンを押すとウィンドウが現れて"終了します"とは表示されるのですが、
"閉じる"を押してもタブは消えず元の画面に戻るだけという状態です。

デザイナー側のプログラム

```html
<div>
<asp:Button ID="btn_terminate" runat="server" Text="終了する" CssClass="button_shared_preference" />
</div>
```

コード側のプログラム

```vb
    Protected Sub btn_terminate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_terminate.Click
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "key", "window.alert('終了します');window.close()", True)
    End Sub
```

補足　2022-02-18
大まかな作業の流れはこちらになります。
１．URLの記載されたQRをiPhoneのカメラで読み込んでサイトにアクセスする
　　サイトロード時に特別な処理は行っていません
２．サイト内でチェックや入力などを行う
　　※重要なことではないので詳細は割愛します
３．”終了する”ボタンを押すと内容をサーバ内に書き出して表示されているウィンドウを閉じる
　　表示されているウィンドウとは"1"でアクセスして"2"で色々と突いたサイトの事です
困っている部分は、"ウィンドウを閉じる"部分です。
サーバ内への書き出しは実装済みです。

Comment: @WebSurfer さん回答関連の解説がこれでしょうか。[JavaScriptでwindowを閉じるやつ](https://qiita.com/rtshaaaa/items/b93e0cd8501411893cba) 類似の何かも併せてこんな記事があるようです。[javascriptサンプル > 「画面を閉じる」](https://web-designer.cman.jp/javascript_ref/window/close/), [【簡単】javascriptでwindowを閉じる例6つを解説](https://webukatu.com/wordpress/blog/16448/)

Answer (score 1):

iPhone の Safari とかでどうなるか不明ですか、普通ブラウザでそういうスクリプトでは閉じないのでは？ JavaScriptで閉じることができるウィンドウは、JavaScriptで開かれたウィンドウのみのはずです。

**【追記 2022/2/18 10:35】**

質問欄に「補足　2022-02-18」を追記されたようですので、それに対するレスを以下に追記します。

> １．URLの記載されたQRをiPhoneのカメラで読み込んでサイトにアクセスする
> 　　サイトロード時に特別な処理は行っていません

それは多分ブラウザのアドレスバーに問題のページの URL を入力して GET 要求をかけたことと同じと理解します。そうであれば、kunif さんが質問欄で紹介された記事にある、

```
window.open('about:blank','_self').close();
```

以外に手はなさそうですが、それで期待通りにクローズできるか否かはブラウザ依存です。iPhone の Safari でどうなるか自分にはその環境はないので不明です。試してみてはいかがですか？

ちなみに、自分の環境で試した限りですが、それでクローズできたブラウザは IE11, Firefox 97.0.1 のみです。

Chrome 98.0.4758.102, Edge 98.0.1108.56, Opera 84.0.4316.14 は close は無視されるようで、open した about:blank が残ってしまいます。

iPhone の Safari で上のスクリプトを使ってもダメなら、そのような裏技的な手段は諦めて、ユーザーが自ら操作してクローズしてもらえるように正攻法で考えることをお勧めします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。そうなると、QRを読み込んでアクセスした場合にタブを閉じるにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: iPhoneのsafariで試してみました。結果としてはabout:blank が残りました。